# Is it possible to have 2 legends for variables when one is continuous and the other is discrete?

Tags: ggplot2

I checked a few examples online and I am not sure that it can be done because every plot with 2 different variables (continuous and discrete) has one of 2 options:

- legend regarding the continuous variable
- legend regarding the discrete variable

Just for visualization, I put here an example. Imagine that I want to have a legend for the blue line. Is it possible to do that??

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to map it to a different aesthetic than you already use:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(gear), size = cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(linetype = "fit"))
```

[image]

There area also specialised packages for adding additional colour legends:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(gear), size = cyl)) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(colour = "fit"))
```

[image]

Beware that if you want to tweak colours via a colourscale, you must first add these before calling the `new_scale_colour()`, i.e.:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(gear), size = cyl)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue")) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(colour = "fit")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = "purple")
```

EDIT: To adress comment: yes it is possible with a line that is data independent, I was just re-using the data for brevity of example. See below for arbitrary line (also should work with the ggnewscale approach):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(gear), size = cyl)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = 1:30, y = rnorm(10, 200, 10)),
            aes(x, y, linetype = "arbitrary line"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But imagine that the line in blue has nothing to do with the scatter data (in the example, blue line seems to be the average)... Is it possbible to have 2 legends?